# How to write a macro to automate a simple task in web browser

Tags: windows, macros, automation, salesforce

I am proficient with web development languages like HTML, CSS, PHP, JavaScript, etc., but I've never written a macro for a desktop and don't know where to start. I was hoping someone can point me in the right direction.

At work, I perform a very repetitive task that involves the following steps:

1. Opening up a lead page in Salesforce (My company's web-based CRM client)
2. Clicking on the email button
3. Selecting an email template
4. Clicking the send email button
5. Opening up a new lead page and repeating steps 2-4

I do this for about 2-300 emails per day. It takes about an hour and a half, and I would like to automate this process as much as I can. I am on Windows. Is there a program out there I can use?

Answer (score 0):

You can automate it with tools like [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/) (IDE is good option for such task if you know JS) or [Sikuli](http://www.sikuli.org/). A list of [GUI_testing/automation_tools](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_GUI_testing_tools). But since you are

> on Windows.

I'm using [PowerShell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_PowerShell) for similar tasks - check my email, login to Firewalls, read news etc. [Here is my article](http://myqaengineering.blogspot.com/2014/08/where-is-my-automation-level.html) of how you can achieve the same using simple user agents. *Feel free to reuse the scripts*.

If you have any questions about the implementation details - just ask me.

- Cheers